# Muting inactive programs

Tags: windows-7, audio

It seems to be a regular occurrence for the game developers that made any given one of the games I run to not mute their program when the program is minimized. Is there a setting in Windows to force minimized programs to be muted? Well, that might not be preferable with Windows Media Player, so unless there's a whitelist for that setting, are there any programs that do the same with a whitelist of their own? I can't seem to find any on Google, but maybe it's just a poor choice of a search query.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is probably to mute it over the mixer.

If we talk for example about DirectSound, the developers have flagged the Soundbuffer with GlobalFocus.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb280907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So far there is no setting to disable this behavior and at least if you don't want to manipulate the memory of your game and set this flag to false, you're best with just muting it on the mixer.

Comment: I know it's certainly possible to detect when a program has been minimized, but is it impossible to shut a program's sound off programmatically through the mixer?

Comment: Well, you could iterate through EnumWindows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and get the state of your window. But muting a foreign program, is surely possible, but never needed to so I'm not sure how you would do it.

Comment: That it is possible, skype is probably the best example. Lowering all sounds if you're getting a call automatically.

Comment: A short look into the ms docs, shows this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Probably exactly what you want